# Deserialize json java object in C#

Tags: java, c#, json, serialization

I am trying to de-serialize a Java Json object in c# using Json Serializer, the same objects I have in Java exist in C#, but i get the following error:

```html
{Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Dynamic4ClientConsumer.Attributes.SurveyResponseAttributes]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
```

here is my Json object:

```html
{
"@type":"concep.selenium.Dynamic.Attributes.SurveyAttributes","surveyType":"1451567316Feedback FormNokia 925 Launch","surveyID":null,"campaignType":"Nokia 925 Launch","surveyStatus":null,"SurveyResponse":
  {"@type":"java.util.ArrayList"},
  "CampaignResponseAttribute":{"@type":"java.util.ArrayList"},
  "questions":{"@type":"java.util.ArrayList","@items":[{"@type":"concep.selenium.Dynamic.Attributes.QuestionsAttributes","question":"Whats your Martial Status?"},
  {"@type":"concep.selenium.Dynamic.Attributes.QuestionsAttributes","question":"Whats your Email?"},
  {"@type":"concep.selenium.Dynamic.Attributes.QuestionsAttributes","question":"Whats your Last Name?"}]},
  "answerses":{"@type":"java.util.ArrayList","@items":[{"@type":"concep.selenium.Dynamic.Attributes.AnswersAttributes","Answer":"Single"},
  {"@type":"concep.selenium.Dynamic.Attributes.AnswersAttributes","Answer":"1451567316email@concep.com"},
  {"@type":"concep.selenium.Dynamic.Attributes.AnswersAttributes","Answer":"1451567316lastName"}]}
  }
```

and here is my object:

```
  public class SurveyAttributes
{
    public SurveyAttributes()
    {
        SurveyResponse = new List<SurveyResponseAttributes>();
        CampaignResponseAttribute = new List<CampaignResponseAttribute>();
        Answerses = new List<AnswersAttributes>();
        Questions = new List<QuestionsAttributes>();
    }

    public string SurveyType { get; set; }
    public string SurveyId { get; set; }
    public string CampaignType { get; set; }
    public string SurveyStatus { get; set; }
    public List<SurveyResponseAttributes> SurveyResponse { get; set; }
    public List<CampaignResponseAttribute> CampaignResponseAttribute { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionsAttributes> Questions { get; set; }
    public List<AnswersAttributes> Answerses{ get; set; }


}
```

I suspect that the problem is the list declaration in Java(ArrayList).
any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem but changing the lib that I was using for serializing my Json object in Java, I was using Json.io which it includes all these unnecessary classes name and annotation. and now I am google.Gson, and it works like a charm!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  public class SurveyAttributes
{
    public SurveyAttributes()
    {
        SurveyResponse = new List<SurveyResponseAttributes>();
        CampaignResponseAttribute = new List<CampaignResponseAttribute>();
        Answerses = new List<AnswersAttributes>();
        Questions = new List<QuestionsAttributes>();
    }

    public string SurveyType { get; set; }
    public string SurveyId { get; set; }
    public string CampaignType { get; set; }
    public string SurveyStatus { get; set; }
    public Questions Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Questions
{
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@items")]
  public List<Question> Questions {get;set;}
}

public class Question
{
  public string Question { get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SurveyAttributes>("// your data here");
```